# How to force AbstractRoutingDataSource to redirect?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an implementation of `AbstractRoutingDataSource`.
During a request, I need to extract data from 2 different databases:
https://github.com/fabricio-ruiz/test-abstract-routing-ds

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
private final CompanyRepository companyRepository;
private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public Controller(CompanyRepository companyRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.companyRepository = companyRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String test(){
        String value = "";
        MultitenantContext.setCurrentTenant(Schema.company.name()); // This is the lookup key for the AbstractRoutingDataSource
        value += countCompanies();
    
        MultitenantContext.setCurrentTenant(Schema.user.name());
        value += countUsers();
        return value;
    }
    
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private Long countUsers(){
        return userRepository.count();
    }
    
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private Long countCompanies(){
        return companyRepository.count();
    }

}
```

The `AbstractRoutingDataSource` use the current value of a `ThreadLocal` Object in `MultitenantContext`.

On the call of `countUsers()`, it throws an error because is trying to find the table users in the previous schema. Is there a way to force it to look again for the datasource?

Thanks in advance!

I've tried to include `@Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)` in the methods but it does not work.

Comment: It is an internal method call so no the transactional won't work. The datasource is already bound to the current thread so switching it isn't an option anymore. It is even worse (and won't even work reliably) if you still have open entitymanager in view in place (which is by default).

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum thanks for your response. What would you suggest? Should I create a new entityManager for it? Another option would be to take the simpler operation and use JDBC. Thanks again!

Comment: If they contain different entities to begin with you already need different entity managers.